# PowerShell :: Get-Counter shows wrong CPU usage

Tags: performance, powershell, azure-sql-database, cpu-usage, taskmanager

Following the [official Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.diagnostics/get-counter?view=powershell-7.1) I found a command that should print the CPU usage:

```
Get-Counter -Counter "\Processor(_Total)\% Processor Time" -Continuous
```

The problem is that it prints the CPU usage with a good 5-10% of discrepancy (click on the GIF to have a better view):

[image]

This is particularly bad because Microsoft [suggests](https://dtucalculator.azurewebsites.net/) the command `Get-Counter` as the official way for DTU calculation before migrating to Azure SQL DB.

Comment: You most likely have to add several of them to get the same output you're saying in task manager. It's using what's called a copy. So get the raw cooked value and do some math

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even if I run:

```
typeperf "\Processor(_Total)\% Processor Time"
```

There is always discrepancy in the CPU calculation.

`Get-Counter` Works as intended, there will always be discrepancy.

You can reduce such discrepancy if you go to Task Manager > View > Update Speed > High

[image]

This way the refresh rate will be higher and the results of `Get-Counter` closer to what you see in the Task Manager. But don't expect to be the same.

Comment: this didn't change anything. get-counter shows 1 to 2% but taskmanager shows 20-30%. this is not just "a little" off... this is totally off

Answer (score 0):

It work with my Computer with no issue.
But in my case it was more reliable when i used -sampleinterval 2

`Get-Counter -Counter "\Processor(_Total)\% Processor Time"  -Continuous -SampleInterval 2`

But as mentioned here:This examples gets continuous samples for a counter every second. To stop the command, press CTRL+C. To specify a longer interval between samples, use the SampleInterval parameter.
[Get-Counter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.diagnostics/get-counter?view=powershell-7.1#example-3--get-continuous-samples-of-a-counter)

What exactly are u trying to do?

Comment: Thank you @PowershellNoob , I updated my question

Answer (score 0):

The below script aligns more closely with Task Manager's CPU% reading:
get-counter '\processor information(_total)% processor utility' | Select-Object -ExpandProperty CounterSamples

Microsoft documentation provides an explanation under the "Cause" heading under the below link.  The article doesn't match this topic exactly, but the explanation provides the answer to the original question.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/troubleshoot/windows-client/performance/cpu-usage-exceeds-100

Comment: Please consider writing your code using a markdown code block, starting and ending with `~~~` to increase the readability of your answer.